# Dispatcher Task /Action Completion

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I have an application which fetches data form the server and gives the result to the user . 
The data being fetched is quite large which blocks the UI for sometime. I am using dispatcher to make it asynchronous.

Here is the code snippet :-

```
private void GetData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      List<result> data=new List<result>;

      DispatcherObject obj= Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,(ThreadStart)delegate
      {
            data =Data.fetch_data(id, name, url);
      });
      if(obj.Completed){
         MessageBox.Show("Done!");
      }
}
```

But the code gives an error saying

> "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation' to
>   'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject' ".

Is there anyway where user can notified when the background task gets completed?

Edit :-

Here is the async/await code

```
private async void GetData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      Task<List<result>> T =Task<List<resultsummary>>.Factory.StartNew(() => data==Data.fetch_data(id, name, url));
       await T;
 }
```

But it gives an error "" The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: Which .Net and Visual Studio version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` does *not* enable you to perform asynchronous actions on a background thread *unless you initialised the `Dispatcher` object on a background thread*. So, instead of using a `Dispatcher` to do what you want, in order to fetch data on a background thread and then pass that data from the background thread to the UI thread, you can use the [`Task` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Task.Factory.StartNew((Func<YourDataType>)delegate()
{
    // Fetch data on background thread here (return YourDataType, whatever that is)
    return DataAccessClass.GetData();
}).ContinueWith((Task<YourDataType> task) =>
{
    // Update controls with result on UI thread here
    YourUiProperty = task.Result;
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Obviously, you'll need to replace the `YourDataType` type with whatever your data type is.

Answer (score 0):

With .Net 4.5 and VS2013 i would recommend the Usage of async and await.

By executing the fetch_data operation on the Dispatcher you are explicitly blocking the UI Thread with your fetch Operation.

```
private async void GetData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // fetch the data in a Background Task and release the UI Thread.
    List<result> data = await Task.Run<List<result>>(() => Data.fetch_data(id, name, url));

    // when completed return to the UI Thread.
    this.MyListBox.ItemsSource = data;
}
```

Even better would be to build an async Version of your fetch_data Operation that Returns a `Task<IEnumerable<result>>`

Comment: Hi ! I tried using async /await but the code gives an error 
" The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." The code is in edit section.

Comment: What does your fetch_data Operation do? if the "data" variable is bound to a UI control you should not set it within the Task. If so, return the Data from your Task with "var result = await Task.Run<..." and set data afterwards "data = result"

Comment: The method fetch_operation connects to server and fetches data from it. Even if you assign data= "the return results of the task " ,it gives the same error. And this statement transfer control to the UI right?

Comment: It's a little bit hard without knowing all the code. But lets try to figure this out. What is id, name and url? Properties, fields? Do you access any UI element in your fetch_data method? When does the exception occur. Try only one line of code in the GetData method: “await Task.Run(() => Data.fetch_data(id, name, url));” exception or not?

Comment: Id,name and url are fields not property and fetch_data does not access any of the UI element . And the one liner gives the same error :\

Comment: If calling the fetch_data method in a Task without doing anythin with the result produces a cross thread Violation, then you definitely access any dispatcher object within your method. Can you post the content of the fetch_data method.